# problem exporting data to snowflake database with DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

I have configured a task to export data to snowflake, I have as source an oracle connection with tables and in destination a snowflake connection, when I run the task  manually it works correctly, but when I create a Schedule and it runs it gets an error.

and when i open my task in edit, the snowflake target tables all change like in picture number 1, as it can’t find the target tables, picture 2 shows the error that DBeaver shows me.

thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIZ5s.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycKYS.png)

create task to exporting data to snowflake

Comment: When you schedule it is it running under a different user than when you run it manually - and that user doesn't have the required permissions on the Snowflake object(s)?

Comment: the other user have the permission on the Snowflake objets , when I use Oracle connection as target , it works fine but not with Snowflake